# Update current activity if my Sqlite DataBase get updated

Tags: android, android-activity, android-sqlite

I'm working on updating my activity which should get updated if there is any update in my Sqlite DataBase .

Any way, My DataBase is successfully updated but I have this button that should be disabled if I update his state to True .

My code to update the Button state to True:

```
  public void InsertEtatReject(String etatReject,int id,String userId)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(EtatReject,etatReject);
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, values,"userID=? AND id=?",new String[]{userId,Integer.toString(id)});
    db.close();
}
```

My button code :

```
  //Verify if button state is True or False
 etat = databaseHelper.getEtatReject(id,username);
  if (etat.equals("False"))
  {
      rejete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view)
          {

              AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(DescriptionList.this);

              // Set the dialog title
              builder2.setTitle("Pourquoi cette annonce est inconvenable ?")


                      .setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                          }

                      })

                      // Set the action buttons
                      .setPositiveButton("Envoyer", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                              final String itemname = (String) items[selectedPosition]; 
                              final int finalId = id;
                              //Update Button state 
                                      databaseHelper.InsertEtatReject("True",finalId,username);
                                      if(itemname.equals("Autre"))
                                      {
                                          Toast.makeText(DescriptionList.this, "Autre ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                      }
                                      else
                                      {
                                          Toast.makeText(DescriptionList.this, "Annonce rejetée :" + itemname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                      }


                                  }

                      })

                      .setNegativeButton("Annuler", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                              // removes the dialog from the screen

                          }
                      })

                      .show();
          }
      });

  }
    else{
      rejete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              Toast.makeText(DescriptionList.this,"Vous avez déja rejeteé cette annonce",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }
      });
```

And to get data From my DataBase I'm using these method :

```
public  String getEtatReject(int id,String userId)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String etat = null ;
    String SelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME +" WHERE userID=? AND id=?";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SelectQuery,new String[]{userId,Integer.toString(id)});
    try {
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                etat = cursor.getString(25);

            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }

    }
    finally {
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

    }
    return  etat;
}
```

Comment: @cricket_007 I've edited my answer.

Comment: Okay, so what have you tried in the code where you have `//Update Button state`? The database cannot modify the button, and the button will not update on its own, so I don't quite understand the question

Comment: @cricket_007 I'am checking from my DataBase if the state is true or false and I'm upsating the state via the method InsertEtatReject

Comment: Yes, that updates the database, but, like I said, that won't automatically change anything about the UI or the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but I would recommend creating some sort of interface that you can pass into your database update method, then have that method call the interface's callback method, like so:

```
public interface MyButtonCallback {

    void updateFromDb(String etat)
}
```

Add the callback as a parameter in your `getEtatReject` method, then call it's update method where you would normally return.

```
public void getEtatReject(int id,String userId, MyButtonCallback callback)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String etat = null ;
    String SelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME +" WHERE userID=? AND id=?";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SelectQuery,new String[]{userId,Integer.toString(id)});

    try {
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                etat = cursor.getString(25); 
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
       }
    }    
    finally {
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }

    callback.updateFromDb(etat);
}
```

Then implement the MyButtonCallback interface with the logic you already have in your button code.

```
//Verify if button state is True or False
@Override
public void updateFromDb(String etat) 
{
    if (etat.equals("False"))
    {
      rejete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view)
      {
          AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(DescriptionList.this);

          // Set the dialog title
          builder2.setTitle("Pourquoi cette annonce est inconvenable ?")


                  .setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                      }

                  })

                  // Set the action buttons
                  .setPositiveButton("Envoyer", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                          final String itemname = (String) items[selectedPosition]; 
                          final int finalId = id;
                          //Update Button state 
                                  databaseHelper.InsertEtatReject("True",finalId,username);
                                  if(itemname.equals("Autre"))
                                  {
                                      Toast.makeText(DescriptionList.this, "Autre ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                  }
                                  else
                                  {
                                      Toast.makeText(DescriptionList.this, "Annonce rejetée :" + itemname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                  }


                              }

                  })

                  .setNegativeButton("Annuler", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                          // removes the dialog from the screen

                      }
                  })

                  .show();
      }
  });

}
  else{
      rejete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
          Toast.makeText(DescriptionList.this,"Vous avez déja rejeteé cette annonce",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      }
  });
}
```

Make sure that the class that contains this button logic `implements MyButtonCallback` and when calling `getEtatReject` just put `this` as the parameter for `MyButtonCallback` like so:

`getEtatReject (id, userId, this)`

Hope this helps!

NOTE: If you could format your code before submitting it to Stack Overflow, that would make it a little bit easier for answerers to quickly solve your problem, getting you your answers faster.

If you are using Android studio the shortcuts to auto format your code are:

<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

on macOS

or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

on Windows/Linux

Comment: Great answer I follow your steps and I get it work :D !